# Terraform mysql provider. Multiple endpoints?

Tags: mysql, terraform

I have database module and I would like to use count in database resource, however I can't use count in mysql provider.
Is there any workaround?

Here is relevant code:

```
provider "mysql" {
    endpoint = "${docker_container.database.ip_address}:3306"
    #CUT CUT
}

resource "docker_container" "database" {
    count = length(var.database_resource_images)
    name       = "db${count.index}"
    image      = var.database_resource_images[count.index]
    # CUT CUT
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? If you want to create a container and then create database schemas or users if there a reason not to do that once and wrap that in a module so you can more easily repeat it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I miss something, but if I create it once and wrap it in the module, I can only use module once per environment (or I'm wrong?). I need multiple database hosts without need to create multiple modules.

Comment: You can reuse a module lots of times, that's the point of them. You'll need to define the interface for them each time and can't loop over them but should be pretty straightforward to declare as many modules you need to create the databases you need

Comment: Thanks man! I really asked stupid question. Now i see it :D